# Выборка из MySQL по дате внутри общего цикла для подготовки данных к отправке в приложение

Tags: php, mysql

Из MySQL необходимо передать данные в приложение. С этим справилась, всё работает. Дополнительная задача к простому процессу - учесть состояние одного из столбцов БД, чтобы передать в приложение значение из этого столбца либо уведомление о том, что данных в нем пока нет. Не могу понять, как оформить результат для этого столбца, чтобы приложение смогло его прочитать.

Приложение собираю в Android Studio, сервер на php, а база данных - MySql
База содержит параметры событий: id, название, дату проведения и т.д.
Всё это собирается календарь. Просто передать информацию в приложение можно (всё работает, если убрать конструкцию if else). Но появилась необходимость смотреть, как добавлена дата. Если мы не знаем точный день проведения мероприятия, дату не заполняем. Т.к. это поле имеет тип DATE, по умолчанию оно заполняется как 0000-00-00. 
Что должно получиться на выходе. Если столбец event_date == 0000-00-00, то в приложение нужно отправить не значение из этого столбца, а текст. Собственно, как это сделать. Условие, которое прописано в коде работает. Не могу понять, что чему присвоить, чтобы приложение получило нужный текст.
Приложение слушает переменную $date

Заранее благодарю!

```
    <?php 

include 'DatabaseConfig.php';
$datetime1 = "0000-00-00";

 $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id_event, event_name, event_date, event_price, image  FROM events;");

 $stmt->execute();

 $stmt->bind_result($id, $title, $date, $price, $image);

 $events = array();

 while($stmt->fetch()){

 if ( $temp['event_date']==$datetime1){
     $d="этот текст должен попасть в приложение";}
     else {
    $d='event_date'; }  

 $temp = array();
 $temp['id_event'] = $id; 
 $temp['event_name'] = $title;
 $temp['event_date'] = $date;
 $temp['event_price'] = $price;
 $temp['image'] = $image; 

 array_push($events, $temp);

 }

 echo json_encode($events);
$con->close();
?>
```

Comment: Вы проверяете массив до его создания. Что за волшебная переменная `$events`, которую нигде не объявили? Что за переменная `$d`, которую никуда не передают?

Comment: $events - это массив. поправила в своем первом сообщении. переменную $d - нужно чему-то присвоить, чтобы строка $temp['event_date'] = $date; брала данные не только из базы, а в соответствии с условием. чему присвоить $d я как раз и не могу понять

Comment: Сначала объявите и присвойте значения `$temp`, потом делайте проверку, которую можно сократить до `if ( $temp['event_date']==$datetime1){
     $temp['event_date']="этот текст должен попасть в приложение"; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$res = $con->query("SELECT id_event, event_name, event_date, event_price, image  FROM events;");
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
    if ($row['event_date']==$datetime1){
        $row['event_date'] = "этот текст должен попасть в приложение";
    }  
    $events[] = $row;

}
echo json_encode($events);
```

Comment: так-то наверное лучше силами SQL

Comment: придется использовать prepare и в итоге получится гораздо некрасивее

Answer (score 0):

```
$events = [];

while($stmt->fetch()){
    if ($date == "0000-00-00"){
        date = "этот текст должен попасть в приложение";
    }
    $events[] = [
        'id_event'    => $id,
        'event_name'  => $title;
        'event_date'  => $date;
        'event_price' => $price;
        'image'       => $image;             
    ];
}
```